# Image fadeout by click on it and replace be new one

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a image list like this:

```
<div class="new-slider">
<ul>
    <li><img src="1.png" alt="1" /></li>
    <li><img src="2.jpg" alt="2"/></li>
    <li><img src="3.jpg" alt="3"/></li>
    <li><img src="4.png" alt="4"/></li>
    <li><img src="5.jpg" alt="5"/></li>
    <li><img src="6.png" alt="6"/></li>
    <li><img src="7.jpg" alt="7"/></li>
    <li><img src="8.jpg" alt="8"/></li>
    <li><img src="9.png" alt="9"/></li>
    <li><img src="10.jpg" alt="10"/></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want to show 5 image from 10, and when i click on any of them it will fadeout and fadein a new image. Always need to show 5 image. It this possible by jQuery, or any slider or gallery can do this?

Comment: Not possible with current technology. We're working on it, though.

Comment: I made this codepen. I cant comment it. I dnt understand their regulations on links. http://codepen.io/PerfectIsShit/pen/YppPdO

Comment: What have you tried so far, Axis? I don't see any programming error here. Only a programming need. What you need are professional web-design services and you are on the wrong website. Come here when you have code of your own that is not working the way you are expecting it to.

Comment: **Finally i got my solution:**
I have done using this jquery

    <script type="text/javascript">
$(".new-slider ul li").click(function(){
 $.when($(this).fadeOut()).done(function () {
   $(this).appendTo(".new-slider ul");
  $(this).fadeIn();
 });
});
</script>